# Iterate over hash of arrays from function

Tags: perl, function, hash

I have an input file:

```
id_1    10  15  20:a:4:c
id_2    1   5   2:2:5:c
id_3    0.4 3   12:1:4:1
id_4    18  2   9:1:0/0:1
id_5    a   b   c:a:foo:2
```

I have many files of this type that I want to parse in different programs, so I want to make a function that returns a hash with easily accessible.

I've not written a function like this before, and I'm not sure how to properly access the returned hashes. Here's what I've got so far:

**Library_SO.pm**

```
#!/urs/bin/perl

package Library_SO;
use strict;
use warnings;

sub tum_norm_gt {

    my $file = shift;
    open my $in, '<', $file or die $!;

    my %SVs;
    my %info;

    while(<$in>){
        chomp;

        my ($id, $start, $stop, $score) = split;
        my @vals = (split)[1..2];

        my @score_fields = split(/:/, $score);

        $SVs{$id} = [ $start, $stop, $score ];

        push @{$info{$id}}, @score_fields ;
    }
    return (\%SVs, \%info);
}

1;
```

And my main script: 
**get_vals.pl**

```
#!/urs/bin/perl

use Library_SO;
use strict;
use warnings;

use feature qw/ say /;
use Data::Dumper;

my $file = shift or die $!;

my ($SVs, $info) = Library_SO::tum_norm_gt($file);

print Dumper \%$SVs;
print Dumper \%$info;

# for (keys %$SVs){
#   say;
#   my @vals = @{$SVs{$_}}; <- line 20
# }
```

I call this with:
`perl get_vals.pl test_in.txt`

The `Dumper` output is what I was hoping for, but when I try to iterate over the returned hash(?) and access the values (e.g. as in the commented out section) I get:

```
Global symbol "%SVs" requires explicit package name at get_vals.pl line 20.
Execution of get_vals.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Have I got this totally upside down?

Comment: Try to `print Dumper($SVs);` see If that resolves your error or It will give you the idea about the returning data from sub.

Comment: Try adding reference dereference operator `->`: `my @vals = @{$SVs->{$_}}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your library function returns two hashrefs. If you now want to access the values you'll have to dereference the hashref:

```
my ($SVs, $info) = Library_SO::tum_norm_gt($file);

#print Dumper \%$SVs;
# Easier and better readable:
print Dumper $SVs ;

#print Dumper \%$info;
# Easier and better readable:
print Dumper $info ;


for (keys %{ $SVs } ){ # Better visual derefencing
   say;
   my @vals = @{$SVs->{$_}}; # it is not $SVs{..} but $SVs->{...}
}
```

Comment: OK great - why is it necessary to use `->`?

Comment: Have a look at [man perlref - Using references](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Using-References) point 3